# the PHP Error Message about Access denied for user (using password: NO)

Tags: php

my php version is 5.2, which is the old verison.
it is because i use the free server
it is my website http://driverrecord.hostzi.com/android_login_api/include/profile.php?username=4

i hope someone can help me. the problem may be about the code.

the error message:

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'a6578726'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/a6578726/public_html/android_login_api/include/profile.php on line 20

profile.php

```
 // array for JSON response
 $response = array();

 // include db connect class
 require_once dirname(__FILE__). '/DB_Connect.php';

 // connecting to db
 $db = new DB_CONNECT();


 // check for post data
 if (isset($_GET["username"])) {

     $username = $_GET['username'];

     // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = $username");

     if (!empty($result)) {
         // check for empty result
         if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

             $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

             $username = array();
           $username["username"] = $result["user_id"];
           $username["first_name"] = $result["first_name"];
           $username["last_name"] = $result["last_name"];
        $username["email"] = $result["email"];
        $username["tel"] = $result["tel"];
        $username["age"] = $result["age"];
        $username["gender"] = $result["gender"];
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // user node
         $response["username"] = array();

         array_push($response["username"], $username);

        // echoing JSON response
         echo json_encode($response);
      } else {
         // no product found
         $response["success"] = 0;
         $response["message"] = "No product found";

         // echo no users JSON
         echo json_encode($response);
       }
     } else {
      // no product found
      $response["success"] = 0;
       $response["message"] = "No product found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
  }
  } else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
   $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

  // echoing JSON response
  echo json_encode($response);


  }
   ?>
```

DB_Connect.php

```
 class DB_Connect {

    // constructor
   function __construct() {

  }

  // destructor
  function __destruct() {
      // $this->close();
  }

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {
        require_once 'include/config.php';
         // connecting to mysql
          $con = mysql_connect("XXXXXwebhost.com", "a6578726_driver", "abcde");
       // selecting database
       mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

      // return database handler
      return $con;
    }

  // Closing database connection
  public function close() {
    mysql_close();
  }

 }

 ?>
```

config.php

```
   <?php
  /**
   * Database config variables
   */
 define("DB_HOST", "XXXXwebhost.com");
  define("DB_USER", "a6578726_driver");
  define("DB_PASSWORD", "abcde");
  define("DB_DATABASE", "a6578726_driver");
  ?>
```

Comment: @CORRUPT `using password: NO` means no password was provided in the connection attempt. It does not mean that no password is necessary to establish a connection.

Comment: @Oswald, yep, reconsidered, thanks.

Comment: `config.php` shows the host/username/etc constants defined, but in DB_Connect your call to `mysql_connect()` is using string literals.  When you get this error are you using the constants or string literals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a `DB_Connect` object is not sufficient to connect to the database. Call `connect()` on that object to connect to the database.

Comment: sorry, i miss to put the code between two comment. i have updated again

Answer (score 1):

You are never connecting to the database. You are constructing a `DB_Connect` instance, but the code in `DB_Connect::connect` is never called. As such, when you run `mysql_query`, there is no active connection. If there's no active connection, `mysql_query` will try to establish a connection with some default usernames and passwords it scrapes together from behind the sofa or wherever, which obviously fails.